# theme options not saving

Tags: functions, theme-options

I've created a really simple theme settings page to just enable my user to add some social media links. However when I input some data and save the fields the text vanish's and doesn't seem to save.

```
<?php
    // create custom theme settings menu
    add_action('admin_menu', 'getextra_settings_create_menu');

    function getextra_settings_create_menu() {

      //create new top-level menu
      add_menu_page('Theme Settings', 'Theme Options', 'administrator', __FILE__, 'ge_settings_callback_page');

      //call register settings function
      add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_mysettings' );
    }


    function register_mysettings() {
      //register our settings
      register_setting( 'theme-settings-group', 'theme_options' );
    }

    function ge_settings_callback_page() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
    <h2>Foxyrentals Theme Settings</h2>

    <form method="post" action="options.php">
        <?php settings_fields( 'theme-settings-group' ); ?>
        <?php do_settings_sections( 'theme-settings-group' ); ?>
        <table class="form-table">
            <tr valign="top">
            <th scope="row">Facebook</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="facebook" value="<?php echo get_option('facebook'); ?>" /></td>
             </tr>
             <tr valign="top">
            <th scope="row">Twitter</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="twitter" value="<?php echo get_option('twitter'); ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr valign="top">
            <th scope="row">Pinterest</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="pinterest" value="<?php echo get_option('pinterest'); ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr valign="top">
            <th scope="row">Google+</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="googleplus" value="<?php echo get_option('googleplus'); ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr valign="top">
            <th scope="row">Linkedin</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="linkedin" value="<?php echo get_option('linkedin'); ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr valign="top">
            <th scope="row">Foursquare</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="foursquare" value="<?php echo get_option('foursquare'); ?>" /></td>
            </tr>

        </table>

        <?php submit_button(); ?>

    </form>
    </div>

    <?php } ?>
```

from this I've created a function that displays these options in the footer using the following;

```
  <?php

function social_icons() {
    $facebook = get_option('facebook');
    $twitter = get_option('twitter');
    $googleplus = get_option('googleplus');
    $linkedin = get_option('linkedin');
    $foursquare = get_option('foursquare');
    $pinterest = get_option('pinterest');
?>
        <a href="<?php echo $facebook; ?>"<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/icon_fb.png" alt="facebook" /></a>
        <a href="<?php echo $twitter; ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/icon_tw.png" alt="twitter" /></a>
        <a href="<?php echo $googleplus; ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/google-icon.png" alt="googleplus" /></a>
        <a href="<?php echo $linkedin; ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/pinterest-icon.png" alt="pinterest" /></a>
        <a href="<?php echo $pinterest; ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/linkedin-icon.png" alt="linkedin" /></a>
        <a href="<?php echo $foursqaure; ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/foursquare-2-icon.png" alt="foursqaure" /></a>

 <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [register_setting()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_setting) should be for all fields like below

```
function register_mysettings() {
  //register our settings
   register_setting( 'theme-settings-group', 'facebook' );
   register_setting( 'theme-settings-group', 'twitter' );
   register_setting( 'theme-settings-group', 'pinterest' );
   register_setting( 'theme-settings-group', 'googleplus' );
  //etc

}
```

Do this for all fields and let me know if you stuck at anything